# JS Regex to match a string with a set of 3 non-concsecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

So i have a string of numbers that i want to run a series of matching tests on.

i have a string of numbers that represent locations on a board. it looks something similar to `'024578'`

Then I test those strings for matches that represent three in a row. So testing for three in the same row is easy, because the numbers are consecutive. i just used the following code:

`const rowsRegex = /([012]{3}|[345]{3}|[678]{3})/g;`

now to check for three in the same column is proving difficult for my limited regex knowledge. i have three sets of non-consecutive numbers and don't know how to write the regex to match a string if all three numbers of a set are present in the string.

i tried variations on the idea i used for rows for the last hour or so on regex101, but havent had any success. i figure it would look something like the following:

`const colsRegex = /([036]|[147]|[258])/g;`

so with the string `013567`, how can i match with the first set in `colsRegex` ?

thank you kindly for any and all help.

Comment: Your `rowsRegex` matches the string `"012345678"` (among others). That doesn't seem to match what you said it was supposed to do...?

Comment: I wouldn't use regular expressions to solve this problem.

Comment: the function returns after the first match, so once it matched `012` the function would end. And I have thought about rewriting this without using regex, but i figured since i was already midway, i would see if there were a way to do it

Comment: I don't think you're even at the beginning. [012] {3} in rowsRegex returns 000, 010, ... up to 222. Can you write by example what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: the string tested will never have duplicate numbers, and it will always only be about 3 to 6 characters long. i just want to know how to get regex to match the set `0 3 6 ` in the string `'013567'` . so if i ran `string.match(regex for 0 3 6)` i would get `true`

Comment: Check /^\d*0\d*3\d*6\d*$/

Comment: yeah that works, thank you a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `RegExp`:

```js
/^\d*0\d*3\d*6\d*$/
```

It should work, given it's copied and pasted from a comment you accepted as working.

Comment: When you copy/paste from comment, give credit to the people that gave the answer with his/her name, or make your answer community wiki.