# Select all characters around word with regex in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to select all characters around some word, but not the word itself with regex in javascript.
 *(Then I will delete the selected part in JS myself.)*
My string is: `[id='s_change_b']`
I want to select **bold** and *italic* part only:

> ***`[id='`*** `s_change_b` ***`']`***

I tried this Regular Expression, but it also selects word inside it.

```regex
/\[id='(.*?)'\]/
```

How can I only select characters around it? I only need **Regular Expression** part. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you meant using the capturing group on the parts on the outside instead `(\[id=')[^\[\]]*('\])` https://regex101.com/r/1DzGzZ/1

Comment: `replace(/(\[id=')(.*?)('])/g, '<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>')`

Comment: That will also make it bold instead of selecting it :-)

Answer (score -1):

```js
replace(/(\[id=')(.*?)('])/g, '<b>$1</b>$2<b>$3</b>')
```

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: Same comment as [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63554979/372239). When you copy/paste from comment, give credit to the people that gave the answer with his/her name, or make your answer community wiki.

Comment: Didn't know I could make it community wiki.  Anyway, the reason I posted this answer was because otherwise this question will sit here rotting without an official answer until the end of time, clogging up the search results even when you filter by "no answer".